# How can I override a native JS function ( canvas's getContext() ) in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, overriding

I'd like to when canvas element calls 'getContext('webgl')', return 'null' value..

I tried to find `WebGLRenderingContext` prototype and update it, but i can't find it.

`WebGLRenderingContext` and `WebGLRenderingContextBase` has no `prototype.getContext`.

How can i change it return to 'null' value?

I've tested with below..

```
var test = document.createElement('canvas');`
test.getContext("webgl");`
```

This returns `WebGLRenderingContext` object...

please help me :)

Answer (score 5):

Messing with native prototypes? Well, I assume you know what you are doing. If so and you really want to overwrite `getContext` prototype method, you can achieve this with simple decorator for `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext`:

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function (orig) {
  return function(type) {
    return type !== "webgl" ? orig.apply(this, arguments) : null
  }
}(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext)
```

So for any context like 2d, 3d, it will work normally, but for "webgl" it will give `null`. No idea, why you need this, though.

Comment: Thank you for help! I tried it and failed but it's my chrome version issue. Thanks

Comment: There are other kinds of webgl such as `webgl2` and `experimental-webgl`. So I used this condition and works for me:
`return type.indexOf('webgl') >= 0 ? null : orig.apply(this, arguments);`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you want to do this, but assuming you *Know Exactly What You're Doing™* you can do it this way:

```js
// store a reference to original vector
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.__oldGetContext = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;

// patch
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(type, options) {
  if (type === "webgl" || type === "experimental-webgl") {
    console.log("WebGL suppressed!");                // remove this in production
    return null;
  }
  else return this.__oldGetContext(type, options);   // call original vector
}

// test (assuming browser do indeed support *webgl...)
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("webgl") || c.getContext("experimental-webgl");

// works with 2D
var c2 = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
console.log("2d?", !!ctx2);
```

You will need to do something similar for `probablySupportsContext()` when it lands.

The key for this to work is to patch before any other code uses the `getContext()` call.

Use at own risk!

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering real implementation and how to change it.

Comment: @N.hwang the main key is to run this before any script that uses getContext(). You can paste it as a script block in the header for example.

Comment: @N.hwang if you BTW mean in native browser code you would have to use the browser source code, find the code location, make the needed modifications relative to the code, recompile... I'm not recommending it, but just in case if this is what you meant. A better approach is to perhaps make a plugin for the browser which do the modification for every page you load, or use something like [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) in FF.

Comment: Thank you ! I have a question.. Umm..When i call 'getContext' in redirected page, it's not working..I think..because HTMLCanvasElement's uppermost parent is 'document'..So, document is reloaded when redirection.. Is it right?
 Document -> Element -> HTMLElement -> HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: @N.hwang yeah, the modification is lost when a new document is loaded. The code needs to be applied to every new document loaded. A plugin can do this, but will of course require every user to have the plugin installed - or if you have access to modify those documents, you can apply the script to each (you can make a small framework for example that embeds all the code you use for the canvas, as well as the initial modification. Then simply link to this for each page using it).