# Remove canvas smoothing for reprojected static image layer

Tags: openlayers

A Static Image layer that requires reprojection does not allow for disabling image smoothing.

Here is the layer I'm using:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: "grid.png",
        imageExtent: [-130, 20, -55, 50],
        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    })
});
```

When zooming in, the pixel edges are blurry (aliased) and they need to be crisp.

The following is ineffective because the prerender hook comes after the projection work inside ol/reproj.js where the canvas is created:

```
layer.on('prerender', function(evt) {
      evt.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
});
```

This is the hack I'm using in the meantime:

```
diff --git a/src/ol/reproj.js b/src/ol/reproj.js
index 7593c6b..5e0d090 100644
--- a/src/ol/reproj.js
+++ b/src/ol/reproj.js
@@ -103,6 +103,11 @@ export function render(width, height, pixelRatio,

   context.scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio);

+  context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
+  context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
+  context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
+  context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
+
   const sourceDataExtent = createEmpty();
   sources.forEach(function(src, i, arr) {
     extend(sourceDataExtent, src.extent);
```

Have I missed something?  Is there a way to do this without rebuilding openlayers?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [How can I override a native JS function ( canvas's getContext() ) in pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111341/how-can-i-override-a-native-js-function-canvass-getcontext-in-pure-javasc)

You could disable smoothing for ***all*** 2d canvas contexts

```
// store a reference to original vector
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.__oldGetContext = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;

// patch
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(type, options) {
  var context = this.__oldGetContext(type, options);   // call original vector
  if (type === "2d") {
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  }
  return context;
}
```