# Trying to scrape items in a canvas with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the High, Low ( These will show by going to settings > scale and enabling their lines ) and current price from this element, a canvas (XPATH: `"/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tr[1]/td[3]/div/canvas[1]"` ) from [this](https://www.dexview.com/eth/0x95aD61b0a150d79219dCF64E1E6Cc01f0B64C4cE) webpage with python, using selenium.

I found some answers that were trying to get back to the JavaScript function done to get the values, I tried but without actually finding anything ( I'm not that good at reversing JavaScript ).

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Which element/text exactly are you trying to scrape?

Comment: I'm trying to get the current price, the one in green/red and the high and low ( they will show after selecting High and Low labels in Settings > Scale )

Comment: _trying to get the current price, the one in green/red and the high and low_: Please [edit the question](/posts/75351988/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the text is actually being drawn client side on a canvas object:
You could inject your own canvas `ctx` by changing the prototype `getContext(...)` method on `HTMLCanvasElement`. Adapting the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111640/6334782):

```js
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.__oldGetContext = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = (type, options) => {
    let ctx = this.__oldGetContext(type, options);
    ctx.__oldfillText = ctx.fillText
    ctx.fillText = (text, x, y, options) => {
        console.log('Drawing text ', text, 'at position ', x, y);
        ctx.__oldfillText(text, x, y, options)
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

You might additionally have to override `strokeText`, and the `getContext` method for the other canvas types.

However, if the text is being rendered server-side, then you're out of luck and have to use OCR. On the other hand, if you just want pricing data, there are loads of crypto (smh) pricing apis out there that would be far less hassle than any of this.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the reply. Second of all, since I'm not really practical in this field, how should I implement this solution?